# Restrict Header editing in excel

Tags: excel

I have a program that reads excel sheet with fixed number of columns, each having a header name. How do I restrict users from entering anything at all in the header cells?

I have done this before using the Data Validation tab to pop a validation message when the user enters any other value in the header cell. Not able to recollect how exactly it was done.

Answer (score 7):

## Use the Protect Sheet Option

First you will want to select ALL the cells in Excel and go to "Format Cells" and then go to the "Protection" tab. In here, De-select the "Locked" tick box.

Now, Select the cells that you DO want to be locked and repeat the process only this time you will be putting the lock in place.

Now you need to click on the "Review" tab and select "Protect Sheet". You will be prompted for a password to unlock the document. Enter a password and you're done. Save it and re-open it and you will see that you are NOT able to edit the cells that you locked. All other cells are editable.